# synchronized static methods

Tags: java, parallel-processing, synchronized

If I have a class with a number of synchronized methods, some of them are static and some of them not:

```
public class A {
    public static void synchronized f1() {}
    public void synchronized f2() {}
}
```

what happens when one thread calls f1() and second calls f2(), it means how they synchronized with each other. and what happens if one tread calls f1() and f1() calls f2() ???

Comment: Probably end up with a deadlock before long.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They're *not* synchronized with each other at all. The static method is synchronized on `A.class`, the second is synchronized on `this`. So it's (almost) as if you'd written:

```
public class A {
    public static void f1() {
        synchronized(A.class) {
            ...
        }
    }

    public void f2() {
        synchronized(this) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

> and what happens if one tread calls f1() and f1() calls f2()

Then that thread will own *both* monitors during `f2`. You should be careful before you do this, as if you take out the locks in the reverse order elsewhere, you'll get a deadlock.

Personally I would urge you to avoid synchronized methods entirely. Instead, synchronize on private, final fields which are *only* used for locking. That means that *only your class* is able to acquire the relevant monitors, so you can reason much more carefully about what occurs while the locks are held, and avoid deadlocks etc.

Comment: if i have 2 threads: T1, T2. T2 calls f2(){ ... f1(); ...}, T1 calls  f1{... notifyAll(); wait(); ...}. if T1 called wait(); , notifyAll() from the f1(), which called by T2 will wake up T1?

Comment: @Michael: It's very hard to follow that code just from comments, and the question isn't clear either. If you have a *specific* question, I suggest you edit that into your original post (or start a new one).

Answer (score 1):

A synchronized static method synchronizes on the *Class* object, rather than an instance.

`f1()` and `f2()` can be called by two separate threads and will execute simultaneously.

See: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#260369

Answer (score 1):

A synchronized static method is synchronized on the class's corresponding Class object, so it's a different lock than the one used by instance methods. Clearly, the static method doesn't have access to `this`. So your f1() and f2() methods are not synchronized against each other, only against other static or other instance methods of the class.